Run a specific partition on a schedule job in dagster
I have the use-case below and not sure how to make this:
I have the following multi partitions:
multiple_partition = MultiPartitionsDefinition({
    "date": DailyPartitionsDefinition(start_date="2024-06-06", end_offset=1),
    "cycle": StaticPartitionsDefinition(['u0', 'u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4']),
})

And I have the below 6 assets (just a simple extract and transform):
extract_AUL -> transform_AUL
extract_FV -> transform_FV
extract_TN -> transform_TN

then, I try to define 5 schedules and 5 jobs to run the assets:
(schedule_1, job_1) -> (6 assets above, only the cycle 'u0')
(schedule_2, job_2) -> (6 assets above, only the cycle 'u1')
(schedule_3, job_3) -> (6 assets above, only the cycle 'u2')
(schedule_4, job_4) -> (6 assets above, only the cycle 'u3')
(schedule_5, job_5) -> (6 assets above, only the cycle 'u4')

I tried to setup this, but no clue how to make the (schedule, job) to run the specific partition per the 6 assets.
the (schedule_x, job_x) always tries to run all the assets and all partitions.
My code to create the job and the schedule is basically like below:
I create the job like this originally:
def create_asset_job(cycle: str, partition: MultiPartitionsDefinition, assets: list):
    return define_asset_job(
        name=f"job_{cycle}",
        selection=assets,
        partitions_def=partition)

And I create the schedule like this:
def create_schedule(cycle: str, hour: int, minute: int, partition: MultiPartitionsDefinition, assets: list):
    return build_schedule_from_partitioned_job(
        job=create_asset_job(cycle, partition, assets),
        description="the schedule",
        name=f"schedule_{cycle}",
        minute_of_hour = minute,
        hour_of_day = hour)

Then, I was thinking the define_asset_job should have some way to specify the partition, so I modify it like:
def create_asset_job(cycle: str, partition: MultiPartitionsDefinition, assets: list):
    ops_config = {}
    for asset in assets:
        ops_config[asset.key.path[0]] = {"config": {"cycle": cycle}}
    return define_asset_job(
        name=f"job_{cycle}",
        selection=assets,
        partitions_def=partition,
        config={'ops': ops_config})

but it doesn’t work either

Ok, finally I make it work by doing the below, the partition selection should be happening on the schedule, not the job:
Job Creation
def create_asset_job(cycle: str, partition: MultiPartitionsDefinition, assets: list):
    return define_asset_job(
        name=f"job_{cycle}",
        selection=assets,
        partitions_def=partition)

Schedule Creation
def create_schedule(cycle, hour, minute, partition, assets):
    @schedule(name=f'schedule_{cycle}',cron_schedule=f"{minute} {hour} * * *",  job = create_asset_job(cycle, partition, assets))
    def the_schedule(context: ScheduleEvaluationContext):
        run_date = context.scheduled_execution_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        return RunRequest(partition_key= MultiPartitionKey({'date': run_date, 'cycle': cycle})
    return the_schedule

I don't know how the exact magic works, thanks to the dagster community.
